# android layout filling space with different size

Tags: android, android-layout, size

I want to make an app that can display images. But the real problem is there : for example i want in the "phone" version in portrait mode to display only one image in a row and in landscape mode two images (like the Youtube app). And to be deduced from this in the "tablet" version, like two images in portrait and 4 in landscape. And to be automatically redirected to the next line.

Here's a good example : I've got 7 images and i want want my layout to look like this in all differents layout :

- portrait mode in your phone : 7 rows (of 1 image for each)
- landscape mode in your phone : 3 rows of 2 and 1 row of 1
- portrait mode in your tablet : 3 rows of 2 and 1 row of 1
- landscape mode in your tablet : 1 row of 4 and 1 row of 3

I don't know if i can be more clear. I just want head in the right direction.

Comment: `GridView` springs to mind although I don't think it's particularly flexible and there may be better ways.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html You make separate layouts for each of your 4 orientations that you are trying to make and android will do the rest for you. Just place them in the directory structure specified here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Off the top of my head I can think of two solutions:

1. Use a [GridView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html). This will automatically place items into an appropriate number of rows/columns based on the size of the screen and the size of the items.
2. Use Android's [built-in features](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) for managing alternative layouts for different screen settings. So you could create portrait/landscape variations of your layout as well as small/medium/large/xlarge variations for different screen sizes. Then you could simply use RelativeLayout, LinearLayout, or whatever you want to actually position the images into rows/columns.

Hope this helps!

Comment: can i set a Max value elements on a row ?

Answer (score 0):

I created a tool that allows you to scale/adjust your layouts for tablets and small screen devices and made a blog post about it here: http://onemanmobile.blogspot.com/2012/04/how-to-scale-your-android-layouts-to.html

Basically, defining your layouts in dp units is not enough if you want your app to fit on all devices and tablets, since there's four different "density-buckets". This tool will allow your layouts to be converted into fitting these density buckets.

In your case, it could scale the grid layout-elements to appropriate size for phones and tablets.